# Скрытые элементы на странице MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Существует ли возможность на движке MediaWiki скрывать контент на странице? Мне необходимо добавлять в статьи блоки, которые могут видеть только администраторы, например:

```
[контент]

[блок №1]
Основная информация
[end блок №1]

[блок №2]
Только администратор видит этот текст
[end блок №2]

[end контент]
```

Comment: Уточните - надо скрыть отображение, или необходимо, чтобы текст "admin only" не был виден даже в исходном коде страницы? В любом случае, рекомендую покопать в направлении (встраиваемых) шаблонов с условным контентом в зависимости от текущего значения переменных (какой-нить {{UserGroup}})...

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы текст не был виден даже в исходном коде страницы, если пользователь не имеет право его просматривать. Спасибо за наводку, буду копать :)

Comment: _Необходимо, чтобы текст не был виден даже в исходном коде страницы_ Значит, изучайте только условные операторы, которые в зависимости от условий отдают разный текст страницы, и не заморачивайтесь на те, что управляют только отображением. Как вариант - попробуйте реализовать шаблон, доступный только админам, и код сокрытия ошибки доступа к шаблону для обычного пользователя.